# ¿Las variables para definir en que carpeta estan los Js, Imagenes, etc en JS vanilla, se guardan en una variable global o de que forma?

Tags: javascript, variables-globales

tal como dice la pregunta, estoy haciendo un pequeño proyecto personal, y para la parte de Javascript (Javascript vanilla es decir no node ni nada adicional) estoy dividiendo los archivos en modulos, así que pense que sería una buena idea, ya no solo para la dirección de estos modulos, si no para donde se encuentren las imagenes etc, tener variables de entorno (entendidas estas como la dirección de las carpetas y otros datos recurrentes de la pagina, que no se si sería más adecuado el termino variable de entorno o de configuración) y así cuando quiera cargar un modulo, un trozo de html, imagen o lo que sea, simplemente sea por ejemplo

import `${_env_js_path + nombrearchivo}.js`

Para hacerlo se que podría usar una variable global, de hecho ya uso una llamada cache, donde almaceno si el usuario ha activado o desactivado la opción de escuchar los sonidos de la pagina, sin embargo no se si es lo más adecuado tener un montón de variables en cache o si es más fácil con archivos .env o similar, he usado el buscador de esta pagina y mirado por google, pero solo me aparece como hacer esto con node no se si en javascript vanilla es igual o si es diferente y por eso la pregunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para evitar caer en opiniones, voy a comentar lo que ya se usa, poniendo como ejemplo Angular:

Al crear un proyecto con Angular, automáticamente se crea un fichero `environment.prod.ts` (hablo de memoria) donde se crea una constante que es un objeto. Este fichero tiene un "hermano" llamado `environment.dev.ts`. El compilador se puede ejecutar pasándole como parámetro el entorno "objetivo":

¿Qué contienen estos ficheros? En el caso del entorno de desarrollo, algo como

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  apiBaseUrl: 'http://localhost:8080',
  imagesFolderUrl: '/static/img/,
  ...
};
```

Y en el caso de producción tienes algo como

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  apiBaseUrl: 'https://mi.dominio-real.com',
  imagesFolderUrl: '/static/img/,
  ...
};
```

En cualquier trozo del código puedes importar este fichero y usar sus valores cuando lo necesites:

```
import {environment as ENV} from '/environment.js';
...
function getUser(userId) {
    return fetch(`${ENV.apiBaseUrl}/api/v1/users/${userId}`).
    then(r => r.json());
}
```

Comment: Supongo en el segundo caso seria production: true, pero vamos se entiende perfectamente y es lo que buscaba, gracias